# Get URL of a file Google Drive after upload it - Android

Tags: android, url, google-drive-api, android-bitmap, google-drive-android-api

In my application I need to take a photo and manage the store of its. I have two option, save photo in Local Memory or in Google Drive and I have to keep track of any photo in a SQLite Database. My application works very good but a I have a big problem:

If I decide to save the photo in Google Drive, when I press OK in the Activity Result of Google Drive (where you choose name of file and the drive folder) I have to get the URL of the file that I have just uploaded in my google drive account.
How can I do this? I suppose I have to do something in `onActivityResult` method.

I left my current application code that's work great!
NOTES: Bitmap `newPhoto` contain the photo take by camera ;)

Thanks You for your answers!

```
private void saveFileToDrive() {

    //Start creating new content and setting a callback
    Log.i(TAG, "Creating new Content");

    final Bitmap image = newPhoto;

    Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(mGoogleApiClient)
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult>() {

                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull DriveContentsResult result) {

                    //if operation was not successful we cannot do anything
                    //and ust fail
                    if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Fail to create new content");
                        return;
                    }

                    // otherwise, we can write our data to the new content
                    Log.i(TAG, "New content created");

                    //creation of an outputstream for the new content
                    OutputStream outputStream = result.getDriveContents().getOutputStream();
                    //Write the bitmap data from it
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bitmapStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bitmapStream);

                    try {
                        outputStream.write(bitmapStream.toByteArray());
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Unable to write file contents");
                    }

                    // Create the initial metadata (Type non title)
                    // NB: user is able to change the title
                    MetadataChangeSet metadataChangeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                            .setMimeType("image/jpeg")
                            .setTitle(imageFileName + ".jpg").build();

                    // Create an intent for the file chooser
                    IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
                            .newCreateFileActivityBuilder()
                            .setInitialMetadata(metadataChangeSet)
                            .setInitialDriveContents(result.getDriveContents())
                            .build(mGoogleApiClient);

                    try {
                        startIntentSenderForResult(intentSender, DRIVE_REQUEST, null, 0, 0, 0);
                    } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Fail to lauch file chooser");
                    }
                }
            });

}
```

[After Take a Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FS4H.jpg)

[Google Drive activity result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wl4J.png)

Comment: `image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bitmapStream);`. Change to `image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);` and do away with the byte array output stream.

Comment: `// Create an intent for the file chooser`. Dont understand this. You just saved content to google drive. Why would you choose a file now?

Comment: I agree with your first answer. thanks
For the second one, I want to allow the user the possibility to change filename and select a different folder where upload the image.

No idea to get the url?